# How to add a setTimeout to a fetch promise that uses redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, promise, fetch-api

After a certain amount of seconds if a fetch promise has not been resolved I want to show a timeout error to the user.

I've seen some good examples of adding a setTimeout to fetch here:
https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/175

But how can I handle timing out a fetch promise that also uses redux? E.g.

```
export function getData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    fetch('blah.com/data')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(getDataSuccess(json)))
    .catch(
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
      dispatch({
        type: DATA_FETCH_REQUEST
      })
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've been dying to have a reason use Promise.race, it works perfectly for this use case. Promise.race waits for the first resolve or first reject. So if reject fires first then it will never fire the `then` on Promise.race. More here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race. Sorry, I didn't get a chance to test the code.

```
export function getData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(reject, 300, 'request timed out');
    })
    let fetch = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch('blah.com/data')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => resolve(json))
        .catch(reject)
    })
    return Promise
      .race([timeout, fetch])
      .then(json => dispatch(getDataSuccess(json)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(getDataTimeoutOrError(err)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome, love this idea, worked really well! Thank you so much!

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise so you do not need to create a new Promise:

`let request = fetch('blah.com/data')...`

and then

`return Promise.race[timeout, request]...`

Answer (score 7):

Based on the snippet from github you mentioned, you can probably do something like this:

```
function timeoutPromise(ms, promise) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      reject(new Error('Timeout'));
    }, ms);
    promise.then(
      (res) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        resolve(res);
      },
      (err) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        reject(err);
      }
    );
  })
}

export function getData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: DATA_FETCH_REQUEST});

    timoutPromise(5000, fetch('blah.com/data'))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(getDataSuccess(json)))
    .catch(
      error => {
        // Change this as necessary
        dispatch({type: DATA_FETCH_FAILED});
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to show an information to the user that the request has failed, you might want to handle the action with the type `DATA_FETCH_FAILED`.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that, however the action DATA_FETCH_REQUEST continuously dispatches and I am getting 'Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection', I guess because its not part of the promise chain?

Comment: What do you mean by continuously? It should fire every time you call the `getData` function. It should also be fine that `DATA_FETCH_REQUEST` is fired outside of the Promise chain, as it's always fired independently of the `fetch` (you could also move it before the call to fetch). Can you locate where the Promise rejection is coming from and why?

Comment: My bad I goofed, had a componentDidUpdate where I was calling the action from, that was causing the loop. This worked, thank you so much. Apologies I had to mark the .race answer as I had no idea it existed and love the idea