# React Native - Timeout on fetching

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How can I set a timeout when fetching an API?

What I want exactly is to try to fetch the data for 10 seconds, if it fails then I want to load the data (saved previously and updated every time that the fetch works) from AsyncStorage.

Probably how I'm doing this is not the correct way, I'm kinda noob at programming (xD). However, this code works just fine on the emulator but does not work on my phone (android). The AsyncStorage seems not to work.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    fetching: false,
    data: []
  }
}

componentWillMount(){

this.setState({ fetching: true })

fetch('http://192.168.1.122:3000/categories.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      data: res,
      fetching: false
    })
  })
  .then(res => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(
      '@Data:Monumentos',
      JSON.stringify(res)
    )
  })
  .catch(AsyncStorage.getItem(
     '@Data:Monuments',
     (err, dados) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error('Error loading monuments', err)
        } else {
            const monuments = JSON.parse(dados)
            this.setState({
                data: monuments
            })
        }
     }
   ))
}
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a setTimeout to a fetch promise that uses redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512238/how-to-add-a-settimeout-to-a-fetch-promise-that-uses-redux)

Answer (score 0):

RN uses whatwg-fetch which doesn't have a timeout. You can work around it by using whatwg-fetch-timeout as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2556#issuecomment-282876518)

That would be simpler than what Micheal above in the comments linked too which is to use Promise.race and setTimeout. Admittedly, pretty clever.

Comment: Hi,

I used this library instead : https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-fetch-polyfill - because I didnt't understood how to use the one you said, sorry :/ 

With this library the timeout works, but one problem tho, when fetching, if it fails on the start he jumps to the catch, and what I want is to wait until the time I defined passes and then jump to the catch... how can I achieve this?

Comment: I got it! Thanks anyway ;)